# 412 when adding an attendee to recurring google calendar event via API with if-match

Tags: google-calendar-api

for non recurring events the "if-match" will return a 412 if the etag specified is not the latest.  However what I found is that for recurring events it seemingly aways returns a 412 (with the latest etag) when trying to add an attendee.  Any ideas?

Comment: seems like this occasionally happens with instances of events as well :(

Comment: I've logged this bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117893507

Answer (score 0):

When you are encountering [this error 412](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#412_precondition_failed), the suggested action would be to re-fetch the entity and re-apply the changes. [Get Specific Versions of Resources documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/version-resources) will have an in depth discussion about suggested action. For an overview:

> Every resource has a version field that changes every time the
>   resource changes — the **`etag`** field. Etags are a standard part of HTTP
>   and are supported in the calendar API for two cases:
>
> - on resource modifications to ensure that there has been no other    write to this resource in the meantime (conditional modification)
> - on    resource retrieval to only retrieve resource data if the    resource has    changed (conditional retrieval)

Comment: In this case I have the latest etag, updated the title to reflect this